How to see individual user path using Google Tag Manager & Mixpanel from the website traffic
I've successfully connected Google Tag Manager (GTM) with Mixpanel and am receiving website traffic data in Mixpanel based on GTM triggers. However, I'm now looking to track and visualize unique users and their individual journeys through the website. How can I achieve this in Mixpanel? Is Mixpanel the best tool for this purpose, or are there other analytics tools better suited for tracking and displaying individual user paths within a website? I'm particularly interested in understanding user flow, drop-off points, and conversion paths. Any insights on tool recommendations or specific setup advice would be greatly appreciated.
I can all user's data in the events (Mixpanel) but unable to filter the events based upon the user's. Right now i'm tracking Page view & page path, i can see from were the user came (intial to current path) of all the users in a single place but i want to see them like user1 user2 so that i can track the users and undersatnd user behaviour on my website.
